# How to lock the position of Y-axis of barchart using achartengine?

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am using achartengine library for implementing bar chart in my application. When user tries to zoom in, it is moving vertically upwards from it's baseline. Is there any way to avoid this??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can control the behavior of the zoom by disabling it on the Y axis:

```
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
```